# Work and travel jobs - which section in the resume does it belong

Tags: applications, terminology

Which section or part in the resume should work and travel jobs belong to?
Summer jobs like beach attendant or officer security.

For someone looking for a job in Electrical Engineering, I do not think it's good idea to put these under Professional Experience.

But having them in the resume it's good I think because it shows someone actually paid for you to do a job.

Answer (score 3):

If they are the only experience you have then put them down. It how that you have worked jobs when you weren't in school. If this is your first post-graduate job HR is used to seeing these jobs listed, and won't trash your resume because they are listed.

Once you have moved a few years past college graduation, these high school and college jobs get dropped. Their ability to showcase the your skills is limited.

Internships may have longer staying power because they are closer to being professional.

There is one caveat to this, background investigations. A company may require a background investigation and may want to talk to previous employers going back 5, 7 or even 10 years. In that case your pizza delivery job will need to be listed on the background investigation form.